# how can I get the marginal distribution of Y when Y|X=x~Poisson(x)?

Tags: probability, random-variables

X~Uniform[0,1] and Y|X=x~Poisson(x). Since $f_{Y|X=x}=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_x(x)}$, then $f(x,y)=f_x(x)f_{Y|X=x}(y|x)$ and $f_y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_x(x)f_{Y|X=x}(y|x) dx=\int_{0}^{1}(1)\frac{x^k e^{-x}}{k!} dx$ I am not sure if this will be a summation and then $f_y(y)=e^{-x}(1-x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marginal (unconditional) distribution of $Y$ is given by $$\Pr[Y = y] = \int_{x=0}^1 \Pr[Y = y \mid X = x] f_X(x) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 e^{-x} \frac{x^y}{y!} \, dx = \frac{1}{y!} \int_{x=0}^1 x^y e^{-x} \, dx.$$  This last integral does not have an elementary closed form, but we can use integration by parts to obtain a reduction formula.  Let $I(y) = \int_{x=0}^1 x^y e^{-x} \, dx$.  Then with the choice  $$u = x^y, \quad du = yx^{y-1} \, dy, \quad dv = e^{-x} \, dx, \quad v = -e^{-x},$$ we obtain $$I(y) = \Bigl[-x^y e^{-x} \Bigr]_{x=0}^1 + y \int_{x=0}^1 x^{y-1} e^{-x} \, dx = -e^{-1} + yI(y-1).$$  This recursion relation, with $I(0) = 1 - e^{-1}$, gives $$I(y) = y! \left(1 - e^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^y \frac{1}{k!} \right).$$  Therefore, $$\Pr[Y = y] = 1 - e^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^y \frac{1}{k!}$$ is the desired probability mass function.

---

The cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is then $$\begin{align*} \Pr[Y \le y] &= \sum_{m=0}^y \Pr[Y = m] \\ &= (y+1) - e^{-1} \sum_{m=0}^y \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{1}{k!} \\ &= (y+1) - e^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^y \sum_{m=k}^y \frac{1}{k!} \\ &= (y+1) - e^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^y \frac{y+1-k}{k!}.\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am kind of confused with that expression, how could I get the cumulative density function: P(Y<=y)?